# Transcriptions cover only the first few minutes of an audio file

Tags: google-cloud-speech

I have tried to transcribe two audio files via the web interface, but instead of getting a transcription of the entire audio file, I am only getting the first few minutes.

The audio files contain normal conversations with the occasional short break. At the point where the transcription breaks off, there is not break. It just stops in the middle of a sentence.

I have tried to transcribe two files with the following settings:

| Parameter | Value |
| --- | --- |
| File type | OGG_OPUS |
| Language code | de-DE |
| Transcription model | Long |
| API version | v2 |

The files were 19'42'' and 22'16'' mins long, but the transciptions end after 5'20'' and 7'06'', respectively. I was "billed" (free trial) for the full lengths of the audio files.

I have listened to the audio files after they had uploaded to see whether something went wrong with encoding or upload, but they play just fine all the way till the end.

What did I do wrong?